# Reporting tool a bit like Crystal Reports for web applications

Tags: reporting

We are looking for a reporting tool, which we can use with all our web applications.

Ideally it would integrate with PHP and would have some kind of report designer which saved templates to be used with JSON data sources  from our applications.

Mick

Answer (score 2):

I went with this:

https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP

So, I can use JasperReports to design the reports, then use PHP to process the data into the report and display the PDF.

Mick

Comment: Mick, you can accept your own answer, in order to help others in future

Comment: Also, I personally have moved from server -side reports which require a complete screen reload to client-side where small parts of the display can be updated with a simple Ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Try https://www.stimulsoft.com/en

Also, consider that the "web" makes integration simple using URIs. You don't need to build a monolithic system around a single subdomain.